# Can I play latest games in VM?

Tags: linux, virtualization

I am a GNU/Linux user and sometimes I would like to play some games. Do VM handle latest games well nowadays?( with good enough hardware of course) What kind of hardware do I need to play let's say Dead Space 3 in a VM with a playable frame rate.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too localized in time (think about what the answer would be in a year, or two years from now), and asking for hardware recommendations is considered off topic per our [FAQ]